# How find the right android:colorControlHighlight color for Material?

Tags: android, material-design

How find the right colorControlHighlight color for Material ?
This is my some theme colors

```
<color name="colorPrimaryDT">#256E93</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDarkDT">#1A4C66</color>
<color name="colorAccentDT">#18ffff</color>
```

Please help find colorControlHighlight or help - how find ? Maybe  - online services, or algoritmes ....

Comment: Look here http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/28484369 too

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Design page](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette) is probably what you're looking for. They have primary and accent colors for a number of different colors. Usually the 500 level is what is used for primary colors.

Comment: This site not help me. On this site dont exist color #256E93 500  . Still wait right answer

Comment: If you're looking for truly Material colors, then you should use the Google specified colors. However, if you want a more general color shade picker, you can try using the [W3 color picker](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp).

Comment: What your exactly advice - for colorControlHighlight ?