# How can I disable Android Lollipop ripple's alpha value?

Tags: android, colors, material-design, ripple, design-guidelines

I have a ripple working with a custom color. However, the color is never fully opaque. According to the answers from [What should be the color of the Ripple, colorPrimary or colorAccent? (Material Design)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484369/what-should-be-the-color-of-the-ripple-colorprimary-or-coloraccent-material-d) it always has an alpha of 40%. Looking at the answers I've tried to use the following v21 specific drawable xml to force an opaque red background once selected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="#ffff0000">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <color android:color="#ffffffff" />
    </item>
</ripple>
```

However, I always get an alpha red, not an opaque red as I want. Is it possible to get an opaque ripple? Here is a screenshot of the ripple, where the red is never fully opaque.

[image]

You can find a simple example of the ripple effect at https://github.com/gradha/Stackoverflow33217896 using an XML ripple and another one generated by code. The latter suggests it is not possible to implement an opaque ripple without rewriting the code.

Comment: As you can see [in source of `RippleDrawable`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.java#L865), `halfAlpha` is computed and applied to the `Paint` object. And that is not configurable, meaning no `if-else` statement to change that with styles or programatically.

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/the-missing-custom-ripple-effect-library-834521721b41

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put alpha value for bounded ripple.

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:attr/colorAccent">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <color android:color="#42ffffff" />
    </item>
</ripple>
```

for unbounded ripple You can set opacity from color if you know your accent color

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@color/accent_26" />
```

colors.xml

```
<resources>
    ...
    <color name="accent">#ff33b5e5</color>
    <color name="accent_alpha26">#4233b5e5</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Color value... Check carefully