# Changing color of Ripple Effect

Tags: android, xml, layout, ripple

I got a ListView where the background is black. Now my problem is that the default ripple effect is also black is the user cant really see it.

How can I change the color of the Ripple Effect without be dependent on API level ? (I want to achieve a white color).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this as your views background:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorAccent">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <color android:color="#42ffffff" />
</item>
```

For more details see this question on stackoverflow:

[What should be the color of the Ripple, colorPrimary or colorAccent? (Material Design)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484369/what-should-be-the-color-of-the-ripple-colorprimary-or-coloraccent-material-d)

And you can use this library for lower apis:

https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect

Comment: Is the <ripple tag not for Api 21 and up ? I have no compiler right now to test

Comment: yes its for api 21+ and you can put this in drawable-v21 @AhmetKazaman

Comment: Whats with all other apis lover than 21 ? I meant I need a solution for all

Comment: for that you can use that library i mentioned in my edited answer @AhmetKazaman

Comment: It does not give bound ripples

Answer (score 1):

Just add 'item: colorControlHighlight' with the desired color in your styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply way to do is define these two colors inside your colors.xml file

```
<color name="ripple_material_dark">#33ffffff</color>
<color name="ripple_material_light">#1f000000</color>
```

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` theme the ripple color can be defined by
adding following line to i.e. Ouline Button style.

```
<item name="rippleColor">@color/outline_button_ripple_color</item>
```