# How to use light ripple on Material Button in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

There are a few places in my app that I place buttons on dark (not white) backgrounds. In this scenario the ripple effect is too dark to see. Is there a way to make the ripple a white color instead of gray?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should be the color of the Ripple, colorPrimary or colorAccent? (Material Design)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484369/what-should-be-the-color-of-the-ripple-colorprimary-or-coloraccent-material-d)

Comment: That doesn't explain how to change the color and asks what should the color be. I know what color I want, but do not know how to change it.

Comment: The answer is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is the way.

Create xml (button.xml for example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/white">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_ripple" />
</ripple>
```

Create button_ripple.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="50dp"/>
    <solid
        android:color="@color/accent" />                
</shape>
```

Change android:color="@android:color/white" in button.xml to needed color for ripple effect and assign button.xml as a background to your button.

@color/accent is the normal state button color.