# What should be the color of the Ripple?

Tags: android, colors, ripple

About the Ripple Color, I had found one answer from 
[What should be the color of the Ripple, colorPrimary or colorAccent? (Material Design)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484369/what-should-be-the-color-of-the-ripple-colorprimary-or-coloraccent-material-d)

But Sometimes, we will use a special color, just like black #000000 or `colorAccent`. And then the `colorAccent_26` won't work perfectly.

Is there guide to get the Ripple Color? Or just use what color you want to use?