# How do I programmatically change the style of a Material Component Text Button in Android?

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

I have a material text button `<Button android:id="@+id/button" style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"/>` that I'd like to change the colour of at runtime. So I set the text colour using `button.setTextColor(Color.rgb(10, 10, 10))`. Unfortunately, this doesn't change the background drawable, so when I click on the button it's ripple colour is unchanged. I'm guessing I need to change the background with something like `attackButton.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.ripple)`, but I'm not sure how to populate the `ripple.xml`. Does this method make sense for changing the button text colour and ripple? If so, how should I write the `ripple.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the colors in the `MaterialButton` you can use:

- `button.setBackgroundTintList` to change the background tint. You should use a selector.
- `button.setRippleColor` to change the ripple color. Also in this case you should use a selector (see below)
- `button.setTextColor` to change the color of the text. Also in this case you should use a selector.

It is the default selector used in the ripple color:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:alpha="@dimen/mtrl_low_ripple_pressed_alpha" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="@dimen/mtrl_low_ripple_focused_alpha" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="@dimen/mtrl_low_ripple_focused_alpha" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="@dimen/mtrl_low_ripple_hovered_alpha" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="@dimen/mtrl_low_ripple_default_alpha" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you :) I forgot to cast the button as MaterialButton so I couldn't see these methods! `(button as MaterialButton).rippleColor = getColorStateList(R.color.button_secondary)`. Also, I set the alpha to .12 because the @dimen alphas are private.

Answer (score 1):

One line of code programmatic no resource file methods for textcolor, backgroundcolor, and ripplecolor:

```
 MaterialButton myMaterialButton = new MaterialButton(this);
 myMaterialButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);
 myMaterialButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
 myMaterialButton.setRippleColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a [RippleDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable)?  Then just Button.setBackground() to different resource or even a [selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496916/how-to-set-state-selected-in-ripple-drawable) xml.  If a ripple with selector won't be enough for you, setting the ripple mask itself can be done

myRipple.xml

```
<ripple android:color="#ffff0000">
   <item android:id="@android:id/myRippleMask"
         android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</ripple>
```

programmatically:

```
LayerDrawable myRipple = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawable.myRipple.xml);
myRipple.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.myRippleMask,Color.rgb(10, 10, 10));
```

with each mask being a different color